# how to hover after calling jquery animate()

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, z-index

i have the following code to grow an image after you hover it:

```
   $(".myImage").hover(function () {
            $(this).find('img').stop() /* Add class of "hover", then stop animation queue buildup*/
                    .animate({
                        width: '560px', /* Set new width */
                        height: '174px', /* Set new height */
                        padding: '20px'
                    }, 200); /* this value of "200" is the speed of how fast/slow this hover animates */
        }, function () {
            $(this).find('img').stop()  /* Remove the "hover" class , then stop animation queue buildup*/
                .animate({
                    width: '140px', /* Set width back to default */
                    height: '44px', /* Set height back to default */
                    padding: '5px'
                }, 400);
        });
```

but the issue is that when the image grows it shows up behind another image (which happens to be a background image) that is to the left of item . . the css on the other image that is showing up over this image is:

```
 .otherImage {
background: url("/Content/Images/main1.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
display: block;
height: 506px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 30px;
position: relative;
width: 527px;
z-index: 0;
```

}

How can i get the image that is calling animate to hover over this background image?

Here is the original css of the image that get called to animate (copied from firebug)

```
element.style {
display: inline-block;
height: 44px;
left: 0;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 0;
padding: 5px;
top: 0;
width: 140px;
```

}

```
.myImage img {
height: 44px;
width: 140px;
z-index: 999;
```

}

```
a img {
border: medium none;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the object you are animating is `position: absolute`, then you can set it's `z-index` to a higher value than the other object and it will be on top.

If it's not `position: absolute`, then we will have to see the relevant HTML markup and all the CSS styling on those two objects to know what your options are.

Comment: i have updated the question with the css of the original image that i am calling animate on

Comment: @leora - we need to see the relevant HTML to understand why one element would be on top of another.  It looks from your animation code like you're just animating `height`, `width` and `padding`, none of the other values are being changed.  Why do you have `left`, `top`, `marginTop` and `marginLeft` in the animation when they don't change?

Comment: you are correct that i don't need left, top, etc . . i have removed those but issue still exists . .what html do you need to see ?